# How to use grep on Linux to report in a verbose way whether a string is present in a file?

Tags: linux, grep

I want to know if `ack_enabled not defined` is present in a particular file `all_defs.txt` and return something, by which I can understand whether the string is present or not.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 18):

Just check the exit code of `grep`. `-q` makes it silent, `!` negates the exit code:

```
if ! grep -q 'ack_enabled not defined' all_defs.txt ; then
    echo Not found.
fi
```

Answer (score 8):

### More vebose one-liner

The following one-liner is even more verbose:

```
grep -q 'ack_enabled not defined' all_defs.txt && echo 'string found' || echo 'string not found'
```